# Bayes factors in pymc3

Tags: python, theano, pymc3

I'm interested in computing Bayes factors to compare two models in PyMC 3. According to [this website](http://stronginference.com/bayes-factors-pymc.html), in PyMC 2, the procedure seems relatively straightforward: include a Bernoulli random variable and a custom likelihood function, which returns the likelihood of the first model when the value of the Bernoulli variable is 0, and the likelihood of the second model when the value is 1. In PyMC 3, however, things get more complicated, because the stochastic nodes need to be Theano variables.

My two likelihood functions are Binomials, so I guess I need to re-write this class:

```
class Binomial(Discrete):
    R"""
    Binomial log-likelihood.
    The discrete probability distribution of the number of successes
    in a sequence of n independent yes/no experiments, each of which
    yields success with probability p.
    .. math:: f(x \mid n, p) = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}
    ========  ==========================================
    Support   :math:`x \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}`
    Mean      :math:`n p`
    Variance  :math:`n p (1 - p)`
    ========  ==========================================
    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        Number of Bernoulli trials (n >= 0).
    p : float
        Probability of success in each trial (0 < p < 1).
    """
    def __init__(self, n, p, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Binomial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.n = n
        self.p = p
        self.mode = T.cast(T.round(n * p), self.dtype)

    def random(self, point=None, size=None, repeat=None):
        n, p = draw_values([self.n, self.p], point=point)
        return generate_samples(stats.binom.rvs, n=n, p=p,
                                dist_shape=self.shape,
                                size=size)

    def logp(self, value):
        n = self.n
        p = self.p

        return bound(
            binomln(n, value) + logpow(p, value) + logpow(1 - p, n - value),
            0 <= value, value <= n,
            0 <= p, p <= 1)
```

Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    p = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
    model_index = pm.Categorical('model_index', p=p)
    model0 # define one model here
    model1 # define the other model here
    m = pm.switch(pm.math.eq(model_index, 0), model0, model1)
    # pass M to a prior or likelihood, for example
    y = pm.SomeDistribution('y', m, observed=data)

    step0 = pm.ElemwiseCategorical(vars=[model_index], values=[0,1])
    step1 = pm.NUTS()
    trace = pm.sample(5000, step=[step0, step1], start=start)
```

Then you compute the Bayes factors as: (add burnin if necessary)

```
pm.traceplot(trace);
pM1 = trace['model_index'].mean()
pM0 = 1 - pM1
pM0, pM1, (pM0/pM1)*(p[1]/p[0])
```

You may also want to check how yo use Information Criteria to compare models, see an example [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/6bbb7911787fa664373e88ae9bd0def2e5b4f7ed/pymc3/examples/notebooks/Model%20Comparison.ipynb)

Comment: What are `model0` and `model1` here? Likelihoods? Observed nodes?

Comment: Also I think `m = pm.switch(model_index, model0, model1)` should be `m = pm.switch(model_index, model1, model0)`. According to the docs `switch(cond, ift, iff)`, so if `model_index` is 1, `model1` is chosen.

Comment: You are right, I edit the answer to make the switch statement more explicit. `model0` and `model1` could be different thinks here, like two different priors or a linear and a quadratic model.

Comment: Have you had any issues calculating BFs this way? From my (limited) experience, fitting identical models to various amounts of data so the correct BF = 1, I generally get woeful BF estimates even with up to a million samples.

Comment: I have only computed BF for simple models. I do not really like BF. I think using information criteria like WAIC is a better approach. Kruschke recommends using pseudopriors to compute BF, maybe you can try with that.